# C# - Storing data in classes

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand how to query a web service that provides information about the weather. The service outputs XML.

I am not sure how to store the retrieved information in a class. Looking on the internet there seems to be two ways of doing it.

Either this way:

```
class CurrentWeather
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureF { get; set; }
    public int WindSpeedMph { get; set; }
    //Lots and lots of more weather related properties
}
```

Or this way:

```
class CurrentWeather
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public double TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public double TemperatureF { get; set; }
    public double WindSpeedMph { get; set; }

    public CurrentObservation(string cityName, double temperatureC, double temperatureF, double windSpeedMph)
    {
        CityName = cityName;
        TemperatureC = temperatureC;
        TemperatureF = temperatureF;
        WindSpeedMph = windSpeedMph;
        }
}
```

My question: I don't know which way to do it. Which approach is the "correct" one, and why is that the case? Why would I use one way other the other?

Comment: For questions where you have working code and only seek advice on best practices, please ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: assuming typo on constructor in 2nd one????

Comment: Probably I retyped it in a hurry

Comment: The differences are one has an *invalid* constructor and the types have changed. *What* is being compared for "correctness"? -1 for failing to provide a clear and *valid* example.

Comment: You have roughly the same code in both files.  Can you post more of your code and how you intend to use it?

Comment: This is all I have so far I'm afraid.

Comment: Both classes have automatic properties so you can initialize the class when you create a new instance. No need for a constructor unless you have logic associated with the data, which could go in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The second is probably heading more the right way to support deserialization, but I'd probably consider breaking the data up a bit.  Keep the data encapsulated so related data stays together.  Your exact structure is up to you, but I'd probably break down something like:

```
public class CurrentConditions {
     public City CurrentCity { get; set;}
     public Temperature[] TemperatureReadings {get; set;}
     public Wind[] WindCondtions {get; set;}

}

public class City {
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public enum TemperatureScale { Celsius, Fahrenheit }
public enum SpeedScale { MPH, KPH }

public class Temperature {
    public int Degrees {get; set;}
    public TemperatureScale Scale {get; set;}
}

etc.
```

It keeps the data organized.  Allows you to only pass around and/or update the particular details you need to if you're making changes, etc.

If you posted the XML I'd have a better feel for how you could map the elements of the XML to objects.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. This is the XML I'll be using: http://api.wunderground.com/api/d36f54198ebbb48c/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.xml

Answer (score 0):

They are exactly the same way to store data, the only difference is you added a constructor to ensure all the parameters are filled when you instance the class.

But it has a drawback, a class without an empty constructor cannot be instantiated by a serializer.

Why I say that?  Because if you are receiving an XML well formed and you code your class structure as the data in that XML, you can use an XmlSerializer to deserialize the XML into an instance of that class without parsing the XML or filling the class properties.